# Getting IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi Exception when data’s are copied from old ignite AKS cluster to new cluster

Tags: ignite

We have deployed ignite 2.8.1 in a new azure Kubernetes cluster (version 1.20.9). There are 2 ignite instances and both of them were working fine. But the problem started when we copied few dat files and it’s corresponding bin files (these are basically persistence files) from an old Kubernetes cluster (version 1.18.10) to this new cluster. After data copy one of the ignite instances started failing continuously, however other instance is up & running. In old cluster also ignite 2.8.1 deployed & there are 2 instances of ignite and everything is working perfectly. I am getting following exception –

```
 [IgniteKernal] Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=o.a.i.i.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
 class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=org.apache.ignite.marshaller.MarshallerUtils$1@101cf747], reconCnt=10, reconDelay=2000, maxAckTimeout=600000, soLinger=5, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false, internalLsnr=null, skipAddrsRandomization=false]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:302)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:943)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1960)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1276)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2045)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1703)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1117)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1035)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:921)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:820)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:690)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:659)
at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:346)
at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:300)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Conflicts during configuration merge for cache
```

Could anyone please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like a Kubernetes-related issue. According to the error, it's about misconfiguration:

> Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Conflicts
> during configuration merge for cache

The below details seem to be truncated, please check the full message and adjust your configuration.

Comment: The truncated part is  as follows: 
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Conflicts during configuration merge for cache 'CLAIMDET' : 
CLAIMDET conflict: 
keyType is different: local=SQL_TNG_CLAIMDET_ebd480b6_d893_44ca_9483_ce05ada51c3d_KEY, received=SQL_TNG_CLAIMDET_db1ec40d_b91d_4b03_83e7_a768c311f831_KEY
valType is different: local=SQL_TNG_CLAIMDET_ebd480b6_d893_44ca_9483_ce05ada51c3d, received=SQL_TNG_CLAIMDET_db1ec40d_b91d_4b03_83e7_a768c311f831

Not sure where in the configuration I have to change

Comment: That's interesting. Unfortunately, I don't know what happened, but most likely storage got corrupted somehow... Could you please upload the full logs from both nodes somewhere?

Comment: Here is the log for the ignite pod which is failing continuously
https://github.com/parth601/ignite_issue_123-/blob/main/Ignite_Pod_1_Exception

Below log is for the pod which is running successfully
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/parth601/ignite_issue_123-/main/Ignite_Pod_0_Success?_sm_au_=iVV6HFtbVvtPMtNJj3tFjKtC88qJW